# Spring boot, eureka, hystrix, turbine: turbine always shows 0 reporting hosts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix, hystrix, turbine

I have an implementation of turbine that is able to discover running services via Eureka:

```
2015-09-08 11:40:13.727  INFO 13112 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instance list for apps: [policy-service]
2015-09-08 11:40:13.727  INFO 13112 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instances for app: policy-service
2015-09-08 11:40:13.727  INFO 13112 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Received instance list for app: policy-service, size=1
2015-09-08 11:40:13.727  INFO 13112 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 1
2015-09-08 11:40:13.728  INFO 13112 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
2015-09-08 11:40:13.728  INFO 13112 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Hosts up:1, hosts down: 0
```

Hystrix is running on the client app, policy-service. I am able to view its stream and see it in the hystrix dashboard.

The issue is that when I view the Turbine stream, I get this:

```
: ping
data: {"reportingHostsLast10Seconds":0,"name":"meta","type":"meta","timestamp":1441734488823}
```

and when I view it in the Hystrix dashboard with the URI `http://localhost:8095/turbine.stream?cluster=DEV`, I just see "Loading..."

I have tried everything mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365202/spring-boot-eureka-server-hystrix-with-turbine-empty-turbine-stream) post to no avail.

Here is my turbine services' application.yml:

```
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
    clusterConfig: DEV
    #http://localhost:8095/turbine.stream?cluster=DEV
  appConfig: policy-service
  InstanceMonitor:
    eventStream:
      skipLineLogic:
        enabled: false
```

I've tried this without clusterConfig and without clusterNameExpression.

Here's my bootstrap.yml:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring:
  application:
    name: turbine-service
server:
  port: 8095
```

And here is my source:

```
package com.ml.turbine;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.EnableTurbine;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTurbine
@EnableEurekaClient
public class TurbineService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TurbineService.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I hit my turbine stream in browser, the log reads:

```
2015-09-08 14:03:19.967  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.t.s.servlet.TurbineStreamServlet     : FilterCriteria: []
2015-09-08 14:03:19.967  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.t.s.servlet.TurbineStreamServlet     : StatsType filters: []
2015-09-08 14:03:19.967  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamingConnection       : Relevance config: []
2015-09-08 14:03:19.967  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamingConnection       : Relevance metrics config: {}
2015-09-08 14:03:19.967  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.t.monitor.cluster.ClusterMonitor     : Registering event handler for cluster monitor: StreamingHandler_92386c8c-b263-4548-be07-10c1a2a3dc27
2015-09-08 14:03:19.967  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.t.handler.TurbineDataDispatcher      : 

Just added and starting handler tuple: StreamingHandler_92386c8c-b263-4548-be07-10c1a2a3dc27
2015-09-08 14:03:19.968  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.turbine.data.AggDataFromCluster      : Per handler dispacher started for: StreamingHandler_92386c8c-b263-4548-be07-10c1a2a3dc27
2015-09-08 14:03:19.973  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.t.monitor.cluster.ClusterMonitor     : All event handlers for cluster monitor: [StreamingHandler_92386c8c-b263-4548-be07-10c1a2a3dc27, StreamingHandler_deaba37e-b712-49db-beba-ab9f60848118, StaticListener_For_Aggregator, StreamingHandler_42896dd8-5d90-43c2-89ad-f57151b94894]
2015-09-08 14:03:19.974  INFO 12024 --- [nio-8095-exec-4] c.n.t.monitor.cluster.ClusterMonitor     : Starting up the cluster monitor for DEV_agg
```

Why am I getting nothing in my turbine stream when it is connected to the policy-service and the hystrix stream works as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my application.yml was configured wrong.

From [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html):

> The clusterName can be customized by a SPEL expression in turbine.clusterNameExpression with root an instance of InstanceInfo. The default value is appName, which means that the Eureka serviceId ends up as the cluster key (i.e. the InstanceInfo for customers has an appName of "CUSTOMERS").

My application.yml now looks like this:

```
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
    clusterConfig: POLICY-SERVICE
    #http://localhost:8095/turbine.stream?cluster=POLICY-SERVICE
  appConfig: policy-service
```

Comment: From http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html#_turbine: `turbine.appConfig: policy-service` and you don't need `turbine.aggregator.clusterNameExpression`.