# Field properties in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.stream.TurbineStreamAutoConfiguration required a bean of type

Tags: spring, hystrix, turbine, hystrix-dashboard

I went through links like: [Spring Boot + Eureka Server + Hystrix with Turbine: empty turbine.stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365202/spring-boot-eureka-server-hystrix-with-turbine-empty-turbine-stream), but still did not worked for me. This question is continuation of **[Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream. in Hystrix Dashboard issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738969/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard-issue)**.

My source code: https://github.com/javaHelper/spring-cloud-cordinating-services/tree/master/Protecting-Systems-with-Circuit-Breakers

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-01-15 10:46:04.141 ERROR 4380 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field properties in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.stream.TurbineStreamAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.stream.TurbineStreamProperties' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.stream.TurbineStreamProperties' in your configuration.
```

Simply trying to start the

**turbine::**

**TurbineApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTurbine
public class TurbineApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TurbineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=3000
spring.application.name=turbine-aggregator
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
turbine.app-config=weather-app,datetime-app
turbine.cluster-name-expression=new String("default")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

remove the turbine stream dependencies from the pom.xml
That should resolve the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine-stream</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to configure Spring to enable configuration properties for turbine?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TurbineStreamProperties.class)
public class TurbineConfig {
}
```

Comment: Could you please suggest where in the code you're suggesting ? My Code Link: https://github.com/javaHelper/spring-cloud-cordinating-services/tree/master/Protecting-Systems-with-Circuit-Breakers

Comment: Your suggestion not working when added to "hystrix-turbine" module. Could you please try yourself please ? It will really help

Comment: Is it [this project](https://github.com/javaHelper/spring-cloud-cordinating-services/tree/master/Protecting-Systems-with-Circuit-Breakers/hystrix-turbine)? I could build it and run it with no problem.

Comment: Project is running fine, however as per think link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738969/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard-issue, Hystrix Dashboard is breaking and not showing metrics.

Comment: Could you please guide further ?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, I tried to run both applications from your repo. Both applications `HystrixDashboardApplication` and `HystrixTurbineApplication` are able to start for me. Have you made any extra config? could you please update your question to be more descriptive?

Comment: Could you please guide me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431036/spring-boot-v2-2-6-release-and-turbine-unable-to-aggregate-the-metrix ?